# Gradle error with jar file on command line

Tags: java, gradle

This is my first time working with gradle so please be patient. I am building a java project and trying to build and compile it with gradle. The code works just fine on an IDE.

I am running into an error on the command line with I run the command below:

```
java -jar build\libs\*****.jar
```

the project builds just fine with:

```
gradlew build
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: source
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:233)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:595)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:581)
    at com.***.MortgagePlan.handleData(MortgagePlan.java:20)
    at com.***.MortgagePlan.main(MortgagePlan.java:10)
```

I am wondering how to fix this error. I have a main class, a customer class along with a text data file in one folder. The build.gradle looks like this:

```
plugins{
    id 'java'

}

jar{
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.***.MortgagePlan'
    }
}
```

My code requires me to import the scanner, input stream and an arraylist. Any ideas?

ps. the * are not the actual names of my files/ directories. I have blocked out sensitive information

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if your build system and/or IDE is running on the same JVM version as the java command. If those are mismatched, certain features may work in the IDE but not in deployment.